# Method is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've linked a button to the following method:

```
- (IBAction)searchButton
{
    NSString *searchText = _searchField.text;
    NSLog(@"lol");
    [_search testSearch:searchText];
}
```

The last line calls the method testSearch within an object named search, defined as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Search *search;
```

Within Search, testSearch is defined as follows:

```
-(void)testSearch:(NSString *)testString
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO");
}
```

My final output, when I click search, is only "lol" (each time I click the button). It does NOT print "HELLO", as testSearch should be doing. I have included testSearch in Search.h, so it should be accessible...why isn't this method being called?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to `[_search testSearch:searchText];`, is `_search` not `nil`?

Comment: I tried initializing it, but I got an error. I'll try again. Not sure exactly how to use lazy instantiation for this yet.

Comment: @rar: Who suggested lazy instantiation? Any weird instantiation voodoo you're doing sounds likely to be the culprit.

Comment: And you want to do `[self.search testSearch:searchText];` ;)

Comment: @Chuck lazy instantiation seems to be a meme in several tutorials and, IIRC, some of the stanford beginner's iOS courses, unfortunately.

Comment: I remember his name, posting a topic about an array yesterday.  Several hours after I made a simple suggestion, he trashed the topic without the simplest form of appreciation.

Comment: Lazy instantiation was indeed taken from the Stanford iOS courses, unfortunately. I had assumed I could trust them :/
@HAS, is there a difference between _search and self.search as far as the code goes? I'm still new to this.
Can someone perhaps tell me the way I SHOULD instantiate this object?

Comment: @TBlue I trashed the topic because my understanding led me to ask a question I wasn't ready to understand yet, and so I deleted the question instead of leaving it hanging because I wasn't ready to understand it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @rar Yes there is a difference. `_search` is your ivar, if you do `[_search testSearch:searchText];` you access that ivar directly! Don't do that except in (all) your `init` and `dealloc` methods (or if you overwrite getters and setters of course). If you use `[self.search testSearch:searchText];` your ivar is retained (generally spoken the memory management is done for you).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Still learning!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start by initializing your `_search` ivar to an instance of `Search` in your designated initializer (or in `viewDidLoad` or some other "user gonna use this" method).

```
- init {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
       _search = [[Search alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}
```

You should *generally* avoid lazy initialization in getter methods for a variety of reasons:

- It adds unnecessary code;  use `@property` and the default synthesized implementations.  Leads to simpler code and less of it.
- a getter that does lazy initialization yields a getter that causes mutation.  That is inconsistent it is quite odd to see a KVO change notification when *calling a getter* (unless, of course, you don't fire the KVO notification... at which point, you have non-observeable mutation).
- a getter that causes mutation is inherently not thread safe unless you add the code, tricky code, to make it so.
- lazy initialization is generally a premature optimization.   Unless you have an identifiable memory or CPU performance issue caused by initializing a resource "too soon", then adding the complexity of lazy initialization is wasted effort.
- lazy initialization can lead to weird ordering dependencies and other complexities.  Far better to have a known entry point for initializing a subsystem than to rely on subsystem X being initialized prior to Y, both by side effect.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because your suggestion and example code make way more sense to me than lazy instantiation ever did (I'd like to know why Stanford is teaching it). I'm going to try it out and report back, but I see no way this wouldn't work.

Comment: I threw this in the init function for the ViewController, but it still didn't work :(

Comment: That is why I suggested `viewDidload` or some other mechanism.  If your instance is realized through unarchiving of a `xib` file, then `init` may not be called (IIRC) and you need to trigger your initialization on `viewDidLoad` or some other after-load deterministic trigger.

Comment: When I tried to `if(self=[super init])` in viewDidLoad, I got an error, saying I wasn't allowed to set `self` outside of init.

Comment: Step back and think it through why that line of code doesn't work.  The object is already initialized prior to `viewDidLoad`.  `viewDidLoad` exists as a hook to perform initialization when the view is loaded and ready to go (it is an explicit delayed loading like I described above).  You only need to set the `_search` ivar;   dump the `if` entirely.   (And, no worries -- you are climbing a very steep learning curve... there is a lot to it and a lot of missteps.  All part of the process.)

Comment: I was away from my code when I responded earlier. Checking back now, it turn out I figured out exactly this late last night, and just forgot about it. So it looks like it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The search object you are sending the message to has not been instantiated so you are sending a message to nil. In Obj-C this does not crash the program, instead it does nothing. Its a best practice in Objective-C programming to perform lazy instantiation in the getter method of the iVar. Additionally, you would have to couple this best practice with not accessing your iVars directly and use the setters and getters for whichever iVar you are trying to access. Below is an example of lazy instantiation in the getter method for your search iVar:

```
-(Search *)search
{
     if(!_search){
        _search = [[Search alloc]init];
     }
     return _search;
}
```

Here is your method call while NOT accessing the iVar directly:

```
[search testSearch:searchText];
```

Comment: It is absolutely *not* the best practice to perform lazy initialization in the getter.  In fact, it has serious potential side effects because that pattern will mean that your getter is sometimes a mutator and, thus, you need to consider both concurrency issues and KVO issues.   The standard practice is to do the initialization in `init` (hence the *designated initializer*) and only optimize away from there when a performance problem has been identified.

Comment: Just following the directions from Paul Hegarty's class, but thank you for the insight- Ill be sure to code with that in mind going forward.

Comment: No worries;   the pendulum has swung on this one over the years.  At one time, lazy initialization was all the rage.

Comment: Ah, yes, The bell-bottoms of Obj-C. I'll code with this in mind. Thanks again.