# Why do the courses at Stanford use the lazy initialisation?

Tags: objective-c, lazy-initialization

Why does the course at Stanford use the lazy initialization for all getters?

Is this correct? Does it have any real advantage?

One advantage (for me) is that the `init` method can become much shorter and you need not check if a variable is allocated.

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate, but definitely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10739726/620197

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to load resources on demand. This way everything loads faster and when needed. In the cases it's not used, it doesn't allocate additional memory.

Comment: ... which ends up moving the cost of initialization to being a side-effect of primary app operations, leading to oft difficult to optimize performance issues and, less often, initialization ordering dependencies that are total pain to debug.

Comment: @bbum ok.... but when i read this
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095452/method-is-not-being-called)
and
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522624/override-getter-only-needs-synthesize)
I have come to doubt if use lazy everywhere.

Comment: Everywhere is not an option. Everything is case-specific. As @bbum says go can meet other issues. Experience is what teaches you how to approach each situation.

Comment: @graver yes, but stanford use lazy everywhere.... why? Paul Hegarty use lazy also when the getter is call immediately after application start

Comment: The projects they demonstrate are too simple to generalise. It's probably just to teach the students about the lazy instantiation. Just a thought.

Comment: Exactly;  lazy initialization works -- and appears to be a great convenience -- in the context of the Stanford courses for the exact reason @graver mentions.    In the real world?   As project complexity grows, having indeterminately ordered code execution will lead to nothing but pain.

Comment: In the Apple ecosystem, lazy init is pretty rare. This is likely the instructor bringing some other paradigm over.

Comment: @@Michael I not too sure of this.